# Keyboard and mouse not responding after booting up 18.04

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, mouse

Since last night I have this weird issue; I can't use my mouse and keyboard after I boot up Ubuntu. What happens is I get to the desktop normally, and I can't do anything. The cursor stays in place, my keyboard doesn't do anything. I tried using other mice and keyboards but that didn't work.

When I boot in recovery mode through Grub however, my keyboard and mouse work just fine. Is there anyone who has a suggestion? Thanks!

EDIT

I fixed the issue by purging all Nvidia drivers.

Comment: Did you try connecting another keyboard and/or mouse via USB after booting?

Answer (score 3):

I've faced this problem before and the problem was `xserver-xorg-input-all` package , so run the recovery mode and enable the network (better to use cable instead of wifi)  and in terminal just type `sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-all` and reboot the system

Hop it'll work

Comment: Thanks Afshin, but I fixed it in the meantime by purging all Nvidia drivers, since the problem occured after updating them.

Comment: Worked for me using i3 on a newly upgraded 19.04.

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 20