# How can I re-enable my mouse/touchpad and keyboard in 18.04

Tags: keyboard, mouse, touchpad

I'm not exactly a newb, but I am when it comes to troubleshooting.  I was attempting to get RDP from my Win 10 box to Ubuntu working so I followed these [instructions](https://www.techolac.com/linux/how-to-connect-ubuntu-linux-remotely-from-windows-via-rdp/)

I did section 1 for *Ubuntu 18.04* and followed everything even the **ufw** portion.  Suddenly my computer froze (or at least I thought it did) and so I held the power button and rebooted.  Now the keyboard and touchpad on my laptop don't work anymore when the login screen comes up.  I can tell it isn't frozen because the time still increments and the screen fades if I wait long enough.

I figured out how to bypass the **GUI** and get into root by holding shift when the laptop is booting, so I disabled **ufw** and **xrdp**, deleted the file I had created, etc.  But when I reboot, I still get nothing.  I can ssh from my Windows machine but I have no idea what I can do to troubleshoot the issue.  I've tried plugging in usb keyboards and mice, but they don't work either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I noticed there was a [related question in the sidebar](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1126138/keyboard-and-mouse-not-responding-after-booting-up-18-04?rq=1), so I checked it out and the solution there fixed my issue.

I ran `sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-all` and now I can use my mouse and keyboard again.